When a foreigner owned LLC receives payments from another foreigner owned LLC, does it become taxable?
Party A has an LLC, which pays no taxes in the US, because it doesn't generate revenue there. The owner lives in Europe and doesn't pay taxes in the US.
Party B is the exact same thing.
Now Party B invoices to party A, for services rendered in Europe.
Does Party B now owe taxes or have to file for taxes or anything like that?
Party A is registered in Nevada.
Party B is registered in Wyoming.
Does it make sense to move the Nevada LLC to Wyoming to simplify things, or can it just stay that way?

why do two parties in Europe who have nothing to do with the US have LLCs in Nevada or Wyoming?

@littleadv because we prefer it that way for all kinds of reasons. And no its not just about taxes.

It relates to the topic in that depending on how this is set up and who the LLC members are, there may be very different requirements in the same scenario. I suggest you discuss it with the attorney that told you to create this set up.

Where Party A or B is registered (Nevada vs Wyoming) has nothing to do with US tax requirements.

Preamble: Generally, it makes zero sense for someone with no US activity to set up a US LLC. It adds costs, and doesn't provide any value other than bragging rights. The foreigner would still need to register the US entity locally, and if it changes anything with regards to the local tax or other obligations - it would be to the worse. For example, in most places in the world, US LLCs are not treated as disregarded entities, and end up creating double-taxation trap for such uneducated foreigners.
As I said in the comments - I strongly advise you to reach out to the attorney that proposed this setup for you to understand the consequences in your local jurisdiction.

That said, in the US:
Corporations
LLCs treated as corporations are US entities and pay US taxes on world wide income. Since the LLC members are foreigners, Subchapter S treatment (colloquially known as S-Corp) is unavailable here.
Partnerships
LLCs with more than a single member that didn't elect to be treated as corporation are partnerships.
Generally partnerships are pass-through, but a reporting return is required (form 1065) in many cases. Whether yours is such a case or not you'll need to determine based on the overall situation, not any specific transaction.
Sole Proprietors
LLCs with a single person member who didn't elect to be treated as corporations are sole proprietors.
In this case LLCs are disregarded entities for Federal taxes, and for the purposes of tax reporting they just don't exist.
State taxes
Neither Wyoming nor Nevada have state taxes, only LLC fees for registration or maintaining them, so state taxes (for this particular transaction) is not a concern. However, depending on the other business activity throughout the year the LLC may be liable for taxes (and tax returns) in various jurisdictions.

It’s also worth noting that the owners of the LLCs are most likely required to report the income and pay taxes on it in their own country. The LLC as well. There could be VAT liabilities as well.

So crossing state lines wouldn't make me liable for federal tax? And Wyoming not having state tax, does that mean I could do business with just anyone in Wyoming and would owe 0 tax?

@user1721135 you should probably talk to a licensed tax adviser. Doing business with anyone in Wyoming can most definitely make you liable for the US Federal taxes. The US is a Federal republic, and state and Federal taxes are orthogonal.
